# Обратная трансформация изображений

Tags: opencv, изображения, c++, captcha

Как можно реализовать сабж? Есть капча (в программе, не на сайте), простенькая. Планирую использовать OpenCV + FANN. По сути, обратная трансформация поможет улучшить качество распознавания. Примеры капчи ниже.

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: А вы знаете параметры _прямой_ трансформации? Если нет, как вы собираетесь искать обратную?

Comment: Судя по изображениям, в принципе можно догадаться как трансформировали. Там либо выпуклые, либо вогнутые, либо чуть сложнее. Если провести прямые по верху цифр, трансформация станет ясна. Вот только надо подвести математику под это.

Comment: Получилось найти ответы? Работаю над той же задачей. Но столкнулся с проблемой шумов на подобных картинках.

Comment: Возможный вариант: найти контуры изогнутого прямоугольника, определить точки принадлежащие граням, определить новые границы прямоугольника, перспективная трансформация из имеющихся к желаемым. На мой взгляд проще расчленить и отдельно распознать по особенностям: вложенные контуры, отношение площадей и прочее.